# Kill a process over SSH by finding Process ID

Tags: command-line, ssh, kill

I want to write a script that let's me kill a process by feeding a command to the script.

I've most of it working but my issue is currently I need to ssh in twice to kill it
1) To get the process ID
2) To kill the process - I'd prefer do this in one go, and I've tried piping, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here is my current working version:

```
ProcessNumber=`ssh user1@server1 -p22222 ps -ef | awk '/[s]sh -f -N -T -R32400:localhost:32400 remote@remote/{print $2}'`
ssh user1@server1 -p22222 "kill $ProcessNumber"
```

And here is the piece of script I can't get working.

```
ssh user1@server1 -p22222 kill `ps -ef | awk "/[s]sh -f -N -T -R32400:localhost:32400 remote@remote/{print $2}"`
```

Any suggestions for getting the second one working in one go?

Comment: Probably privilege issues. To which user that `pid` is owned ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parsing output of `ps -ef` is a bit tricky. I'd recommend you use `pgrep` as

```
pgrep -f `ssh -f -N -T -R32400:localhost:32400 remote@remote`
```

Or just reduce everything with `pkill`:

```
ssh user1@server1 -p22222 "pkill -f 'ssh -f -N -T -R32400:localhost:32400 remote@remote'"
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm interested to know why the second option here only uses an escape \ at the end?

Comment: Sorry Just noticed that was the other way around / What's it for? - I think it might be rogue

Comment: @denski  I need to edit it out actually - it's the remainder of your original awk example :)

Comment: cool, thanks. This is the cleanest working one anyway.

Comment: if you do `ssh "pkill -f other_process; other_command;"` ssh will start a bash script of the form `bash -c 'pkill -f other_process; other_command;'` which pkill will terminate (thus preventing `other_command`) so you need to add a layer of escaping by doing something like this `ssh "pkill -f \\`echo o\\`ther_process; other_command;"` so that `pkill` won't recognize its own bash parent process.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this ugly one-liner can do that:

```
ssh user1@server1 -p22222 "kill \$(ps -ef | awk '/[s]sh -f -N -T -R32400:localhost:32400 remote@remote/{print \$2}')"
```

The escaping might still need some adjustments (didn't test it).

Comment: I'm interested to know if using the escape \ is only related to the initiall SSH request. Once that happens do they become legitimate variable markers?

Comment: @denski the backslashes are intended for your current shell, so that it doesn't try to perform command substitution. In other words, it tells your shell to treat it as plain text

Comment: Excellent, learned something new!